# In ApplicationWillTerminate Viewcontroller is nil

Tags: swift3, xcode8, viewcontroller, option-type, appdelegate

In my AppDelegate in ApplicationWillTerminate I created a variable:

```
let firstVC = FirstViewController()
print(firstVC.lbl.text)
```

After I terminate the app, the app crashes because "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". After I did some checking apparently the Viewcontroller is nil.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is FirstViewController & why are you creating it inside ApplicationWillTerminate?

Comment: What Gagan_iOS said plus I doubt that `FirstViewController` is nil. Instead I guess `lbl` is an outlet which is not connected when you don't instantiate `FirstViewController` from a storyboard or don't load it from a NIB.

Comment: I'm trying to save lbl.text as a UserDefault in the ApplicationWillTerminate and no the outlet is connected.

Comment: Use if let or guard to avoid crashing app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, I can't imagine that `firstVC` is nil because the only way it could be would be if its init was failable, which is impossible because you cannot override `UIViewController.init()` with a failable one and even then the compiler would complain that you would have to say `print(firstVC?.lbl.text)`. Which illustrates the beauty of Swift's optional types.

To verify: `print(firstVC.lbl)` should print nil. The logic that connects the outlets is only run when you instantiate `FirstViewController` from a storyboard or load it from a NIB.

Anyways, if you just create a new instance of `FirstViewController` this will *not* reflect whatever changes the user has made to its elements "on screen" but every element including `lbl` will have its default value.

Possible solutions:

- Get the active `FirstViewController` instance in `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` and save its `lbl` text
- I don't know what your app is doing but views should show your data model so rather save your data model.
- Have a look at [Preserving and Restoring State](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html) and probably the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) in general.